# ETL Pull failing, error message giving mixed messages

Tags: gooddata

When following the instructions on http://developer.gooddata.com/article/loading-data-via-api, I always get a HTTP400 error:

> 400: Neither expected file "upload_info.json" nor archive "upload.zip" found (is accessible) in ""

When I HTTP GET the same path that I did for the HTTP PUT, the file downloads just fine.

Any pointers to what I'm probably doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoodData is going trough migration from AWS to RackSpace.
Try to change of all get/post/put requests:

- secure.gooddata.com to na1.secure.gooddata.com
- secure-di.gooddata.com to na1-di.gooddata.com

Comment: Wow, good shot. Hard to guess given the error, but it did solve it − more details here: http://developer.gooddata.com/article/rackspace-project-migration-process

Comment: Glad to help, I am pretty experienced with all kind of errors. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the datacenter where the project is located via /gdc/projects/{projectId} resource - the "project.content.cluster" field.

For example:

https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/projects/myProjectId:

```
{
"project" : {
  "content" : {
     "cluster" : "na1",
....
```

For AWS this field has an empty value, "na1" means rackspace.